# return objects on the fly in php

Tags: php

I know this can be done in javascript like so:

```
function doSomething(){
    var something, something_else, another_thing;

    // do something with these vars

    return {
        attribute1 : something,
        array1 : [
            something_else,
            another_thing
        ]
    }
}
```

can it be done in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new object of `stdClass()`, assign its attributes and return it.

```
$x = new stdClass();
$x->attribute1 = "something";
$x->array1 = array(1,2,3);

var_dump($x);

return $x;
```

Comment: or $x = (object) array('attribute' => "Something", "array1" => array(1,2,3)); return $x

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not support object [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29). However, it does have a generic `stdClass` class, which you can [typecast an array into](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) for a somewhat similar syntax.

```
function doSomething()
{
    $something = 1;
    $something_else = 2;
    $another_thing = 3;

    return (object) [
        "attribute1" => $something,
        "array1" => [
            $something_else,
            $another_thing
        ]
    ];
}

var_dump(doSomething());
```

will give ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MY8xxv))

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { 
    ["attribute1"]=> int(1) 
    ["array1"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> int(2) 
        [1]=> int(3) 
    } 
}
```

Note that you can only use [short array syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays) as of PHP 5.4. Before that you'd use [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php).